# Star rating and data fetching from localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is a part of a bigger app.
In this part I am trying to rate by using stars and I am storing that rate data locally and retrieving data on reload.
I am missing the part when I reload the page, that I get the rate from previous session i.e. to get 5/10 stars black.

```
<div class='rating'>
<span class='star' id="1" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="2" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="3" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="4" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="5" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="6" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="7" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="8" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="9" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
<span class='star' id="10" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
</div>


let s = JSON.parse(localStorage.s || null) || {};
const saveStar = (id) => {
s.id = id;
console.log(s.id);   
}
function loadData() {
return s.id || "default";
}
console.log(loadData());

.rating { font-size: 0; }
.rating span { font-size: 40px; }
.rating span::before { content: "☆"; }
.rating span.active::before {content: "★"; }
.rating span:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to access localStorage via StackOverflow code example below will result in an insecure operation. I've took the liberty of creating an example that will default to using an obj key pair in the event LS isn't available as well, so you can see it in action.

You can use the `localStorage` by setting and getting key/value pairs for this simple example. If you are planning on saving bigger datasets with arrays, etc, then using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` would be appropriate for reading and storing with LS.

Further info on how to set/get key value pairs using LS can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

This example could be further flushed out to also check if clicking on first star when it is already selected, to result in 0 stars being orange, etc. Also, some more modern ES6 structure could probably be utilized.

```js
var exampleWithoutLS = false;
var testWithOutLS = {};

function saveStar(id) {

  if (!exampleWithoutLS) {
    localStorage.setItem('rating', id);
  } else {
    testWithOutLS.rating = id;
  }

  // Refresh our rating on screen
  loadData();
}

function loadData() {

  // Get stored rating on load
  var rating;
  if (!exampleWithoutLS) {
    rating = localStorage.getItem('rating');
  } else {
    rating = testWithOutLS.rating;
  }

  if (!rating) {
    return;
  }

  var s = parseInt(rating);
  // Get all of our stars..
  var stars = document.getElementsByClassName("star");
  // Loop through, and based on rating int, apply style
  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    if (i >= s) {
      stars[i].classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      stars[i].classList.add("active");
    }
  }
  // return s;
}

try {

  // Check we can access localstorage
  if (!window.localStorage) {
    console.log('Unable to access LS');
  }

} catch (e) {
  // Can't access LS
  exampleWithoutLS = true;
} finally {
  loadData();
}
```

```css
.rating {
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating span {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.rating span::before {
  content: "☆";
  color: black;
}

.rating span.active::before {
  content: "★";
  color: orange;
}

.rating span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Star Rating</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='rating'>
    <span class='star' id="1" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="2" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="3" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="4" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="5" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="6" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="7" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="8" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="9" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
    <span class='star' id="10" onclick="saveStar(this.id)"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage APÏ setItem and getItem function to store and retrieve the note.

From the doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Local_storage):

```
// Save data to the current local store
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");

// Access some stored data
alert("username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the value of a variable (`s` in your example), but never persisting it back into `localStorage`. One way would be:

```js
let s = JSON.parse(localStorage.s || null) || {}
const saveStar = id => {
  s.id = id
  console.log(s.id)
  localStorage.setItem('s', JSON.stringify(s)) // <====
}
function loadData() {
  return s.id || 'default'
}
console.log(loadData())
```

See the full API on how to use `localStorage` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage